# Why does git clean --dry-run shows more untracked files than git status does?

Tags: git, github

Ok so I forked a project, ran `git pull upstream master` and git status said working directory clean. I then ran some tests from the project

now `git status` shows

```
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   activemodel/log/
```

now `$ git clean -d -f -n` shows

```
# Would remove actionpack/test/temp/
# Would remove activemodel/log/
```

These are just directories for log files but I'm curious why `actionpack/test/temp/` shows up in the `git clean dry run` but didn't show up in `git status`

This could cause problems if all untracked files don't show up in `git status` and then `git clean` would delete files you didn't realize it would delete.

Anybody know why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are they empty directories?

Git does not track empty directories (actually Git does not track directories at all, as you can read in the [Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F)), so they will not appear in `git status`, but they would indeed be cleaned by `git clean -f -d`.

That's why a dry run of such `git-clean` command is showing directories that do not appear otherwise with a regular `git status`.

As a side note, this is also why some people add a placeholder file, sometimes called `.gitinclude` by convention, inside empty directories in order to make Git track them.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. `activemodel/log/` has an empty test and development file, while `actionpack/test/temp` has no files. It is an empty directory so it doesn't show in `git status`. Now I understand. Thanks